# Checking to see where a function was called in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on some software that reads from a file system using a specific inputstream reader. This class has a function called read() which is used in some driver program to read files. I want to find out the location/source file for the driver program. If I only know where read() is implemented how can I find where it is used?

Comment: Do you have an IDE (such as Eclipse) and the source code for everything? Then you can "Show Call Hierarchy".

Comment: Ctrl+alt+H in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command on the top-level directory of the project to find where read() is used:

```
grep -n --recursive " read(" *
```

This will recursively search all the files for the string " read(" and print out which file it is in, as well as the line number.

Unfortunately, knowing where read() is implemented won't directly tell you where it is used.  The implementation of a method is not dependent on where it is used, that's the other way around.  If it were dependent, every single library in the Javadocs would have information about all the obscure programs that used such a library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can modify `read()` you might get a stack trace. Either throw an unchecked exception or do something like

```
StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
```

Comment: This will only print out the first instance where modifying read() breaks the program.  The code dependent on this might also use read(), and won't get called.  Also, read() might be called in other program conditions than the one that is run a given time.

Comment: @La-comadreja Using the print code I have here will find all invoked `read()` calls and will not break. Throwing an unchecked exception would halt the jvm. OP wants to know where a function *was* called, not where it *might* be called.